# How can I assign a role to a member who sent a message in discord?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

How I can add a role to a member who sent a message like `!color common`

I've searched over the web and found a solution like this:

```
import discord
from discord.utils import get

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
      return
  if message.content == '!color common':
    role = get(message.guild.roles, name='common')
    await message.author.add_roles(role)
```

However, it returns `discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions`. But I've already let permitted it to be an administrator. How can I fix this? Thank you!

Here is the full error message:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 314, in on_message
    await message.author.add_roles(role)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/member.py", line 676, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 241, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Comment: maybe the bot doesn’t have the permissions necessary? or it’s too low on the hierarchy

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński It doesn't seem like it though. I have given him administrator which means that he has all permissions.

Comment: @CELLSecret drag the bot role to the top of the role list

Comment: @FluxedScript Follow up question: It worked but it doesn't work when I try ```await message.author.delete_role(role)``` where it says ```"Member" object does not have delete_role``` How can I change it to make it work?

Comment: `await message.author.remove_roles(role)`

Comment: Thanks. I got it :D